# Google safe browsing not detecting url even it unsafe url

Tags: php, google-api, safe-browsing-api

I am using Google Safe browsing Lookup api v4, but some url not detecting by api even it unsafe. My request data and request header like below:

```
    $request_data = [
        "client" => [
            "clientId" => "#########",
            "clientVersion" => "1.0"
        ], 
        "threatInfo" => [
            "threatTypes" => ["MALWARE", "THREAT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING", "UNWANTED_SOFTWARE", "POTENTIALLY_HARMFUL_APPLICATION"],
            "platformTypes" => ["ANY_PLATFORM"], 
            "threatEntryTypes" => ["URL"], 
            "threatEntries" => [
                        ["url" => "http://www.urltocheck1.org/"],
                        ["url" => "http://www.urltocheck2.org/"],
                        ["url" => "http://www.urltocheck3.com/"]
                     ]
        ]
    ];
    $request_headers = [
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    ];
```

I am sending urls in bunch of 500 url in one request.
Anyone can help me solved this issue? What is missing in my request or do anything else to detect unsafe url.
Also I was try sending that unsafe url only in request but can't get it in response that it is unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

I had noticed the same. I created a script to visit various known and new phishing pages via a browser and keep track of how many times you get the red warning page and compare it with the response from the API. 
If I recall correctly it was about 20% of the sites that were blocked on brower but not blocked via the API.

I had documented some of my findings at: https://www.wandera.com/mobile-security/google-safe-browsing/

My best guess is that GSB, through their data sharing program with other security vendors, can block websites on the browser (if a trusted vendor says this is malicious) but cannot provide this result back on the API if it is not originating from their own threat intelligence source. This way the third party vendor that participates on the data sharing program can protect their IP.

Thanks,